# Python MySQL: Not showing inserted records

Tags: python, mysql, insert

I am using Python 2.7 with MySQLdb 32bit, alongside with MySQL 5.5.8 running local.

I am driving myself crazy over this, I have never seen anything like it.

Basically, I am inserting records into MySQL from Python via:

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root", passwd="mypassword",db="python",port=3307)
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(myfield) VALUES(%s);","somedata")
```

I have verified that it is connected properly and that it can successfully `SELECT` data from the database.

Here is the odd part:
From MySQL Query Browser (GUI tool) AND from MySQL via CMD, I am unable to see the inserted records.

I can insert and select records from my Python Script, but they DO NOT show up in my database, it just returns `Empty Set (0.00 sec)`

And here is the really weird part:  I can truncate and delete data from the GUI tool and from the Console.

To sum up:  I can insert and select data from the Python Script.  I can not see that data in MySQL.  However, I can truncate and delete that data using MySQL.

I am completely lost at this point.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your code works in the console but not otherwise, I believe you need to add the line

```
db.autocommit(True)
```

After you connect or you need to do `db.commit()` after your inserts.

Comment: Is the `commit` method not on `db` in this case?

Comment: You are absolutely right @exhuma, my mistake.

Comment: I wish I could have found that in the examples in the documentation... Thank you!!! I will accept your answer in approx. 4 minutes!